# How to determine which calendar an event is on?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

Is there an easy way to determine which calendar an event is on?

For example, if I have an the ID of an event I can do the following:

```
Event event = graphClient
            .me()
            .events()
            .byId(eventId)
            .buildRequest(options)
            .get();
```

Now that I have that event, how do I determine which calendar it is from? There appears to be a calendar property in the event, so I could try to do something like

```
String calendarName = event.calendar.name;
```

For some reason though, the calendar property is always null so that won't work.

Comment: Have you looked at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331543/how-to-get-calenders-events-by-calendar-name-with-microsoft-graph-and-nodejs?

Comment: That's not the same thing. I already have an event, and I want to know which calendar it came from. They're just trying to get all events from a calendar. It seems to me that an event should have knowledge of which calendar it belongs to, but I can't seem to figure out how I might do that.

Comment: You can use the [Calendar relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) with expand query parameter like this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{eventid}?$expand=Calendar` and get the Calendar id and later use the call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarid which you got}` to get the name of calendar. :)-

Comment: Moving this to Answer :)-

Comment: Hi gottfred, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hi Shiva, I was waiting for a response to my other comment since getting the name of the calendar was the original goal stated in my question. Thank you for your help. Marking as solved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Calendar relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) with expand query parameter like below.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{eventid}?$expand=Calendar`

Now you need to get the Calendar id and later use the call shown below.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarid which you got}`

to get the name of calendar.

Comment: Thanks, the calendar property inside the event object is no longer null. However, the name property within that calendar is still null. I now have the calendar id, so I could query for it at this point, but is there a way to get that name property to load correctly right off the bat that I'm missing?

Comment: No, its by design and you need to get the calendar name through calendarid only using calendar endpoint(`/me/calendar/calendarid`). :)-